# MySQL update select from same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How can I update column for the same table with this query:

```
update products 
set (related_product_id) = 
(
select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from products
INNER JOIN products_cross on products_cross.product_upc = products.upc
WHERE products_cross.related_product_upc = 2631695
)
```

PRODUCTS table before:

```
id   |   upc   |   related_product_id  |
3721 | 2631695 |                       |
4566 | 37262   |                       |
3723 | 173615  |                       |
3724 | 216571  |                       |
```

PRODUCTS table after:

```
id   |   upc   |   related_product_id  |
3721 | 2631695 |  4566,3723,3724       |
4566 | 37262   |                       |
3723 | 173615  |                       |
3724 | 216571  |                       |
```

PRODUCTS CROSS table:

```
product_upc | related_product_upc |   
37262       | 2631695             |  
173615      | 2631695             |
216571      | 2631695             |
```

Comment: What you are trying to Update.On which basis. Please explain

Comment: Provide your table definitions for better understanding your schema

Comment: I wan't to implode products id's based on another table (products_cross). No, current query doesn't work: "You can't specify target table 'lc_products' for update in FROM clause"  or "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(related_product_id) = 
(
select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from products
INNER JOIN' at line 2

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Storing comma-delimited ids is a really, really bad idea and not at all the SQLish way to store data.  I would suggest that you learn about how to properly represent data.  If you like, ask another question and explain the data you have -- you can get a better data model.

Comment: Your update query does not make any sense, because the subquery has no relation to the outer update.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: When using only SELECT part it works as wanted. Just can't get it working together with UPDATE.

Comment: Do this: Show us _three_ records from the `products` table _before_ the update, then show us what those three records look _after_ the update.  If you can't do this, then you're not even ready to ask a question here IMO.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], e.g. a dump of a suitably tailored toy database. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be something like below

```
update products p1
join (
   select c.related_product_upc ,GROUP_CONCAT(product_upc) related_products
   from products p
   join products_cross c on c.related_product_upc = p.upc
   where c.related_product_upc = 2631695
   group by c.related_product_upc 
) t on( t.related_product_upc = p1.upc)
set p1.related_product_id = t.related_products;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1d1f/1)

Note: storing related products as a comma separated values is a bad design instead you can create a new table and relate your products so that each relation will be stored as a single row

```
related_products

product_id related_product_id
3721        4566
3721        3723
3721        3724
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to do as below example:**

Use the mysql local variables

```
SELECT 
  @product_id_list_comma_separated := GROUP_CONCAT(table1.id) 
FROM
  products AS table1 
  INNER JOIN products_cross 
    ON products_cross.product_upc = table1.upc ;

UPDATE products AS table2 SET table2.related_product_id = @product_id_list_comma_separated;
```